# Google Maps InfoWindow Not Popping Up When I Browse Back to Page

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps Javascript V3, I have a map set up with some markers. I have a listener on each marker that pops up an InfoWindow on a click event. This works just fine. The problem is when I click on any link on the page and then browse back to the original page, the InfoWindows stop displaying. I have put in alert statements in the listener, so I know the listener is running, but I cannot figure out why the InfoWindows are not showing up.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var viewable;
var markerArray = new Array();
var infoWindow;
function initialize() {
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "holding..." });

    var mapOptions = {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoom: 15,
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var loop_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 42.341111, -71.080707 );
        marker = addMarker( loop_latlng, "<strong>$1,495.00</strong> <br> Columbus Ave <br> 0 beds / 1 baths <br> <img src='/images/71428455_0.jpg' width=150> <br> <a href='/mls_rn/8305'>get more details</a>" );
        bounds.extend(loop_latlng);        

        var loop_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 42.340022, -71.0657278 );
        marker = addMarker( loop_latlng, "<strong>$2,000.00</strong> <br> Union Park St <br> 2 beds / 1 baths <br> <img src='/images/71426623_0.jpg' width=150> <br> <a href='/mls_rn/8253'>get more details</a>" );
        bounds.extend(loop_latlng);        

    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    showMarkers();
}

function addMarker(location,contentString) {

  var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    content: contentString,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
    infoWindow.setContent(this.content); 
    infoWindow.open(map,this);
  });

  markerArray.push(marker); 

  return marker;
}


// display all the markers on the map
function showMarkers() {
  if (markerArray) {

    for ( i in markerArray ) {
      markerArray[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }
}


function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCICKRjJ3Vo_l2hy5uV7GdkYBot6jCtZzI&sensor=true&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

I think this actually may be a Rails issue. If I cut and paste this into an HTML document, it seems to work just fine; however, within my Rails app, I'm seeing the off behaviour. The one thing I notice is that the maps seems to reinitialize in the pure HTML case, but doesn't seem to do so in Rails. I'll look into this more and comment. If anyone has seen this before; however, please chime in!

Comment: Does it work if you initially trigger `loadScript()` via other means (not on `load` event of `window`)?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe doesn't happen for me on the [official info windows samples](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple), so i'd expect your code to behave the exact same way.

You would need to manually program for such functionality. On HTML5 compliant browsers, you can use the [`pageshow` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) to open the info window manually. However all current (less than 10.0) versions of Internet Explorer don't support the event so you would also have to handle this in the window `load` event.